# Can different SES instances in different accounts each receive emails in the same region with the same domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, dns, amazon-ses

This article shows you can have two accounts each with an SES instance running in the same region and same domain and each instance is able to **send** messages (see photo below) [https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/how-to-use-domain-with-amazon-ses-in-multiple-accounts-or-regions/#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20same,same%20account%20but%20different%20regions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/how-to-use-domain-with-amazon-ses-in-multiple-accounts-or-regions/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20same,same%20account%20but%20different%20regions).

Is it possible for each SES instance to **receive** emails using this setup? Each SES instance would have its own address such as email1@example.com and email2@example.com where example.com is the domain.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can, the domain must be verified in both accounts and [you'll have to create a ruleset](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/receiving-email-receipt-rules-console-walkthrough.html) in each account with the recipient condition in each account that matches the two emails respectively.

Comment: But is there a way to control which specific email messages get sent to which AWS account? My understanding is that you add an MX record to the domain and specify each AWS account with a priority. Then email messages will be distributed to the AWS accounts based on the priority.

Comment: they all get sent to AWS, and the rules decide where it gets received to. I don't see a reference to account number in the MX records per docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/receiving-email-mx-record.html